# Перемещение окно

Tags: c#

Как можно перемещать окно программы двигая окно (форму)

Answer (score 1):

WinForms - ручками, отлавливать `MouseMove`, `MouseDown`, `MouseUp`.

WPF - `Mouse.Capture`

Comment: Выше указанные события и банальное изменение Location для нужного окна.

Comment: При нажатии запоминаем координаты, разрешаем движение, при движении меняем Location, отпуская, запрещаем движение.

Comment: В таком случае вопрос не по адресу. Читайте правила форума.

Comment: А ну ок и что бы новую тему не создавать подскажите сборку для webclient и для StreamReader

Comment: Первый в System.DLL, второй в mscorlib

Comment: using System.DLL;
using mscorlib;
пишет не правильно

Comment: > Первый в System.DLL, второй в mscorlib

Вы что, руками подключаете стандартные библиотеки фреймворка? В вашей IDE ничего по дефолту не подключено?

Comment: Нет   ) )  )